# How to share a project on multiple repositories using Subversive in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I am new to SVN and this question may seem silly to some experts here.

I have 1 project shared on 2 different SVN repositories, e.g.,

https://project1.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

https://project1.someotherplace.com/svn/trunk/

How do I configure in Eclipse Subversive, so that I can synchronize the project on 2 different  repositories?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have two copies of your project in two unrelated, disconnected repositories/servers in the first place? That's not how Subversion is meant to work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying to make a copy on another subversion repositories, just in case the other one goes down.

Comment: If you want a backup, then you need to either [replicate the repository in a read-only state](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication), or make [backups with `svnadmin dump` or `svnrdump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.backup). But doing what you describe above is a descent into madness.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this reliably, AFAIK. With Subversion, a working copy can only be associated with a single repository. You might be able to do some hijinks with relocating repeatedly, but be prepared for lost work and mass confusion.

Keeping a single project in multiple repositories is a recipe for disaster unless you're using mirroring (which is configured at the server end, not on clients) of some sort.